# AC_SUBST macro usage in Makefile.am SUBDIRS

Tags: autotools, automake

In configure.ac, I have:

```
AC_SUBST([with_dir2],[dir2])
```

In some Makefile.am, I have:

```
SUBDIRS = @with_dir2@
```

which seems to work.

But using

```
SUBDIRS = dir1/@with_dir2@/dir3
```

does not work (the string @with_dir2@ goes straight in the makefile without any substitution)... why? and what is the workaround :-) ...

Comment: The best I have found so far is AC_SUBST([with_dir123],[dir1/${with_dir2}/dir3]) and SUBDIRS= @withdir123@. Not nice... any better idea?

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to accomplish? The `automake` documentation describes how to deal with optional subdirs. Are you choosing one subdir from a selection? Maybe making each choice a conditional subdir would work in that case.

Comment: I am trying to use a parameter to given "configure" as a build directory. For instance, if I write 'configure --with_dir2=dir2' I would like 'dir1/dir2/dir3' to be "sub-automaked" (i.e. be done by SUBDIRS). I cannot restructure the project at this time (so the path to put in SUBDIRS ARE dir1/<with_dir2>/dir3).

Answer (score 1):

Automake automatically emits all `AC_SUBST` variables as `Makefile` variables as well.  So you can rewrite that to:

```
SUBDIRS = dir1/$(with_dir2)/dir3
```

I always preferred this approach anyhow because it is nicer for debugging -- you can override the variable on the `make` command line for testing.

Comment: Sorry,  I am probably missing something obvious but I get: error: required directory dir1/$(with_dir2)/dir3 does not exist. When running automake.  SUBDIRS is a variable used by automake. Thanks for looking at it. Hope I am doing wrong :-)